# Как в ansible запустить эфемерный контейнер lxc?

Tags: ansible, lxc

Нужно запустить контейнер с разовой работой из ansible. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Ну минимум через `shell` и `lxc_container`. В чём проблема?

Comment: где запустить? Я работаю с Proxmox там есть свой модуль по создание VM (виртуальная машина) и CT (контейнер) есть AWS, Kubirnaits, AZURE, Vagrant, VirtualBox, Hardware, Windows, GNU/Linux  где можно запускать... https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lxc_container_module.html